# If $\forall y\in B, y=h(x)$ where $x\in A$, is it true that $\exists y$ s.t. $y=f(x), x\in A$ for every $y\in B$?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I know it is not great grammar, but is it logically incorrect to say something like

If $\forall y\in B, y=h(x)$ where $x\in A$, it is true that $\exists y$ s.t. $y=f(x), x\in A$ for every $y\in B$

Comment: What is $\exists y (\textrm{some condition}) \forall y$? It doesn't make sense to me. Also, try using words instead of symbols!

Comment: It is a mistake to write something of the form $\exists y \cdots \forall x$. This mimics common English usage, but it is ambiguous (even in English): it could mean $\forall x \exists y \cdots$ or $\exists y \forall x \cdots$ (the latter is the likely reading of the English equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying $[\forall y \in B (f(y) = x)] \implies [\forall y \in B (\exists y \in B (f(y) = x))]$, this is indeed true. If you're saying $[\forall y \in B (f(y) = x)] \implies [\exists y \in B (f(y) = x)]$, this is not necessarily true (for consider $B = \emptyset$).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your thoughts. I believe I understand your notation but () specifies order of logic without "such that"s muddling things up, correct?

Comment: @Coletti Precisely. By phrasing the situation with parenthesis and in formal logic, I hope to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: Gotcha. As a curious thought, is the first statement (you said is indeed true) a necessary $\implies$ or could it be an $\iff$?

Comment: You can't make it an $\iff$. The first thing to note is that $\forall y \in B (\exists y \in B (f(y) = x))]$ is in fact equivalent to $\forall y \in B (\exists z \in B (f(z) = x))$ - that is, the inner $y$ corresponds to the $\exists$ and not to the $\forall$. So consider the case $f(x) = x$, $B = \{0, 1\}$, and consider the case where $x = 1$. The $\iff$ does not hold.